# Call Oracle stored procedure from PowerBI

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, powerbi

I am using PowerBI (64b) with an Oracle 11g database.

When I try to connect to Oracle by stored procedure, I get an error, I don't know if I'm doing it right. please appreciate any help.

Observation: if there is a connection to the database, I can list the tables, etc.

I'm not calling the stored procedure correctly, what should I change? Thanks a lot,

```
procedure SPU_LISTAR_1(

FINI IN DATE,

FFIN IN DATE,

RS_CURSOR_LISTA IN OUT TYP_CURSOR)

AS 

BEGIN

OPEN RS_CURSOR_LISTA FOR

    SELECT IDPROCESO,CAMPO1

FROM TABLA1

WHERE FECHA BETWEEN FINI AND FFIN ;

END;
```

This is how I call this stored procedure from PowerBI:

```
DECLARE RS_CURSOR_LISTA  SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    [STOREDPROCNAME]('01/01/2019','05/01/2019');
    DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(RS_CURSOR_LISTA);
END;
```

And this is the error I get:

> An error was encountered while trying to connect.
>
> Details: "Oracle ORA-06550: line3, column1":
>
> PLS-00201: Identifier 'SPU_LISTAR_1' must be declared
>
> ORA-06550: PL / SQL: Statement ignored
>
> pls-00302: Component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared
>
> ORA-06550: PL / SQL: Statement Ignored

Comment: 1. Did your procedure compile well without errors? As of current text there's no semicolon at the end of `select` statement, that's why it should return error in compilation. And what is `TYP_CURSOR`, where it was declared? 2. What is `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`?

Comment: Hello, the stored procedure works fine, it was an error when writing it, DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT, I found some examples of stored procedure calls that used this command line, I really do not know how to call the procedure I am trying different alternatives. how could i start?

Comment: TYP_CURSOR= TYPE TYP_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR